# How to resolve SnakeYAML type dynamically

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I have a YAML file defined as below:

```yaml
policies:
  - endpoint: /user/add
    log: true
    evaluator: consumer
    data:
      - 
        key: external
        whitelist:
          - name
      - 
        key: internal
        whitelist:
          - name
          - email
          - a_phone
```

I want to determine the type dynamically at runtime by the field "evaluator". For example, when evaluator is "consumer", the type in array "data" is ConsumerDef, when evaluator is "conditional", the type in array "data" is ConditionalDef. In other words, the type in array "data" is determined by field "evaluator" at runtime. I do not want to add this "!!com.xxx.policy.def.ConsumerDef" in array "data".

Is it possible to do this, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You have to implement your own Constructor in SnakeYAML

Comment: I have tried it, worked very well, thanks!